# What is the default tool tip style

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

What is the default tool tip style that appear using "title" attribute.
I want to know the text family,background color, text color,border color etc.

Comment: it looks different on every browser

Comment: hover your mouse to share button below my posted question i want the exact same style

Comment: @ozil: exact same style like what? It looks different on IE, dirrerent on Chrome, different of Firefox and so on. And it also depends on the version of the browser. Which one do you like?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome (other browsers work too, but process may be different) open tooltip, press right mouse-->inspect element --> view the css for the toolbox on the right

Comment: That doesnt matter, you should be still be able to see the css of the tooltip, even if it is closed